# How to import maven project to JIdea when maven project file is named other than pom.xml?

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea

Is it possible to import maven project to JIdea when maven project file is named other than pom.xml? Like "pom.atrifact-name.jar.xml" for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in current IntelliJ IDEA versions, please [vote for the open issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-22472).

Comment: Not only in 11th, but also in 10th and, probably, all downwards.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create a pom.xml and make the weirded name pom.xml to be its' module.

Comment: what if you have three more project definitions with weird names and they already have a parent project - and they are located in the same folder?

Comment: How did it happen? Its not even close to [best practices](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects)..

Comment: And does the most upper project reside in its own pom.xml?

Comment: This is what normal people call legacy code. And there're other who don't want it to be touched.

Comment: What happens in IntelliJ when you load the top parent?

Comment: :) you don't have an error because there's no <modules><module></..></..> declaration inside top parent.